# Remove all the pubnub channels in a channel group using a single api call?

Tags: pubnub

I wanted to remove all the channels with in a channel group in a single api call. it is possible ? or do we have to iterate through the list of channels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Channel Groups - Removing all Channels

You can do this using the `remove group` API (name varies per SDK). For JavaScript, the [function is named channel_group_remove_group](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-controller#removing_channel_groups_by_name)

```
pubnub.channel_group_remove_group({
  callback: displayCallback,
  error: displayCallback,
  channel_group: channelGroup
});
```

This must be called from the app that is subscribed to the channel group. In other words, it can't be called on behalf of the client by the server.

If you want to have your server add and remove channels to and from channel groups (on behalf of the clients), then the server's PubNub instance needs to be [granted the *manage* permission](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#grant) (if you are using Access Manager, otherwise, anyone can do this) and just add and remove channels from those channel groups.

You can [provide a list of channels to be added](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#add_channel_to_group) or [removed](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#cg_remove_channels) but you do have to iterate through the channel groups that the channels need to be added to or removed from.

Comment: Hi i understand that Each client connection (instance of the PubNub object) can subscribe to a total of 10 channel groups. my question is can we add and remove channels without subscribing to a channel or channel group ?.

Comment: I wasn't referencing the *10 channel group* scenario, but rather the ability for a client to remove a channel group (not just unsubscribe from the channel group) which will remove all channels from the channel group and unsubscribe from the channel group. Adding additional details about add/remove channels via the *manage* permission on the server.